# How can I detect if the return value from parseInt(localStorageService.get('xxx')); is NaN?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
        getPageTypes: function ($scope) {
            $scope.option.pageTypes = [
                { id: 0, type: 'Edit Basic' },
                { id: 1, type: 'Edit Standard' },
                { id: 2, type: 'Report' }
            ];
            $scope.option.selectedPageType = parseInt(localStorageService.get('xxx'));
        },
```

How can I set the $scope.option.selectedPageType to be the value 0 if there is no entry stored in localStorage for "abcd" ?

Comment: Have you tried the [`isNaN()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) yet?

Comment: Have you also tried: `$scope.option.selectedPageType = parseInt(localStorageService.get('xxx') || 0);`

Comment: So will `localStorageService.get('xxx')` always return a number if it's valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this shorthand method to initialise your selectedPageType variable:

```
$scope.option.selectedPageType = parseInt(localStorageService.get('xxx')) || 0;
```

Be careful using the native isNaN method proposed as the MDN documentation states that it is a [broken function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description). For example, it will return true for non-number values, such as undefined.

If you have the [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) Javascript library available you may also consider using _.isNaN

Comment: Don't waste time with a library - it's as easy as `x !== x` - only if `x` is NaN will that be true.

Comment: While some output from `isNaN` can be confusing, it is not a broken function as you state. To reduce confusion take this example: `someVar - 0` produces a `NaN` if `someVar` is not a number, else it gives you a Number. `isNaN(someVar - 0)` would therefore guarantee you that you would get the expected result from `isNaN`

Comment: @DarkoZ - `isNaN(null)` returns `false`, as does `isNaN("")`, that's what's meant by "broken". The function's name doesn't accurately reflect what it does, you have to read the spec to see that it tries to convert its argument to a number _before_ testing whether it is not a number...

Comment: @nnnnnn if you have `x = NaN;` and then call `isNaN(x)` you get `true` right? The `x !== x` trick works only when `x` is a literal `NaN` as per above. So if `x` is unknown, you STILL have to forcefully try to convert `x` to a number before you try either `isNaN` or `!==` right? So the question is, which one of the two ways shows a clearer intention?

Comment: @DarkoZ - OK, I guess the "trick" is to understand that `isNaN()` is not testing whether the argument is numeric, it's testing whether it is actually the value `NaN`. So (unlike what I said in my previous comment) the function's name does reflect what it does, but in a way that is confusing in that the average person is likely to expect it to mean "Is the argument numeric?"

Comment: @nnnnnn have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/93Z6u/3/ - I've used the same samples as from MDN

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `isNaN()` function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN